# isotope multiple combined filters hide empty filters

Tags: javascript, filter, jquery-isotope

I've been trying to apply more than 2 combined filters to this great piece of code but I can get it to work, any solution, thanks a lot in advance

[Isotope v2 Grid - Multiple Filters - Hide empty filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549656/isotope-v2-grid-multiple-filters-hide-empty-filters)

Answer (score 0):

here's the working [codepen](https://codepen.io/codebling/pen/NWqyqKq) for two filters:

what I need is to hide unavailable options on the other filter dropdown once you've selected a first filter, in the example works perfectly for two filters but I need it for 3 or more
thanks

```
<https://codepen.io/codebling/pen/NWqyqKq>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like I've got it, even though I have to add a function for every filter (on select change), it would be great if anyone knows how to deal with this with only one for all the selects

```
    [Codepen - Isotope - combination filters with multiple selects and reset button - Disabling option on filter][1]
```